# How to setup an efficient way to save volatile information to a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a web service where I would like to get the following output (which partially already works) as result to an API Request.

**Request**

I built an API which accepts the following request:
`POST` `http://server.com/v1/requests/"`
with some parameters send over in the message body.

**Response**

`Status-Code: 200 OK`

```
{
    "transaction_id": "12345",
    "status": "processing"
}
```

**Table: Requests**

This creates a new request on the server in a table called `requests`. The table consists of the fields (simplified):

```
transaction_id -> String
status -> Int
```

I have another table for the users in the system

**Table: Users**

This table holds the info about the users in the system registered.

```
user_id -> String
LatLng -> Float
```

**Search for users nearby the request location**

The algorithm I have is as follow:

- When I send this request to the server, I am starting a search for the nearest 3 users in the range of the request made. This search is being performed on the users table and returns an array of users that are near the location I am searching for (code not being displayed, but works fine).
- This array of users is sorted by distance (nearest to farest) so I know which users are close to the request position.
- I send a Push Notification to these 3 users where they will be asked if they can respond to this request. They can choose to accept or decline. Their decision should be saved to the database

When I make a request then to a particular request, I will create the following response:

**Response**

```
{
    "transaction_id": "12345",
    "responders": [
        {
            "user_id": "R001",
            "dispatch_time": "1234"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "R002",
            "dispatch_time": "1235"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "R003",
            "dispatch_time": "1236"
        }],
}
```

This workflow is clear to me. What is totally unclear to me is now how I need to implement the table structure/algorithm that it is efficient. So my questions are:

1. Where do I store the information about the 3 responders that have been found by my database query? I can think of ways at the moment: One would be by adding additional fields in the `requests` table that each hold an `user_id`. I would think of something like:

`|transaction_id|status|user_id_1|user_id_2|user_id_3|`

`|12345         |1     |U100     |U200     |U300|`

I would then update the same table entry for each user that responds to the request and at the end would only have one entry in the table.

The other way I thought of, would be:

`|transaction_id|status|user_id|`

`|12345         |1     |U100`

`|12345         |1     |U200`

`|12345         |1     |U300`

This seems somehow strange to me. Don't I blow up my whole table with data at the end as I then have 3x the amount of data? How is it done in an efficient way?

So what would be the right algorithm/structure to receive the output I am wishing for?

Comment: please use the second method

Comment: Why is the second method the appropriate one?

Comment: Cleaner and not limiting on top of my head. If you add a column you 1st limit yourself to number users for transaction (if that number increases, well.. update the app), you might end up with a huge table if changes increase. The latter is easier, cleaner IMO

Comment: @sesc360 Read about database [normalization](http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/MDBS01CD/page_26.htm)

Comment: But wouldn't that expand the dataset by 3x if 3 people answer the same request?